# Asignar pesos a diferentes clases de keras

Tags: python, keras

estoy intentando entrenar un modelo de red neuronal convolucional para 5 clases.
Estas clases estan muy desbalanceadas, de esta forma:

0: 25810

1: 2443

2: 5292

3: 873

4: 708

Como veis la clase 0 tiene inifinidad de datos mas que el resto. Entonces para obtener un buen modelo necesito balancearlas.
Actualmente estoy utilizando este fragmento de codigo que luego le paso al fit_generator:

```
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
           'balanced',
            np.unique(train_generator.classes),
            train_generator.classes)
```

el problema es que no noto diferencia alguna, y segun leo, esto es lo que utiliza todo el mundo. ¿Es esta una buena forma de balancear las clases o deberia utilizar otro método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `compute_class_weights` en el parámetro **class_weight** tiene tres opciones:

1. `balanced` donde el mismo determina la *importancia* de cada clase según la distribución de los datos mediante la siguiente formula.

   ```
    class_weight = n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))
   ```

Donde **n_samples** es el número total de datos, **n_classes** es el número de clases en el dataset y **np.bincount(y)** hace un conteo de todas las ocurrencias de cada clase, es decir el número de datos por clase, que ya tienes.

Para esos datos que muestras al usar `balanced` internamente se crea el siguiente diccionario que le reduce o aumenta la importancia a ciertas clases, de manera que se le de una mayor importancia a las clases poco representadas y viceversa.

```
    { 0: 0.27218907, 
      1: 2.8756447, 
      2: 1.32751323, 
      3: 8.04719359, 
      4: 9.92259887 }
```

2. `dictionary` la segunda opción para definir estos pesos es hacerlo manualmente en un diccionario y esto requiere de un entendimiento amplio de los datos y del problema que estás trabajando. Por ejemplo, que la clase 4 sea de vital importancia para el problema que estás trabajando y no reconocer esta clase significa una perdida enorme de dinero.

   ```
    { 0: 0.25, 
      1: 3, 
      2: 1.5, 
      3: 8, 
      4: 50 }
   ```
3. `None` o no usar nada, en este caso todas las clases tendrán igual importancia.

Estas son las formas que existen para determinar los pesos de las clases en el entrenamiento, para notar **diferencia** entre usarlas o no debes elegir un punto de vista y cambia según el dataset que tienes. Por ejemplo, está demorando más en entrenar con o sin pesos, mi modelo converge cuando uso pesos balanceados por fórmula o manualmente, como se ven las matrices de confusión y las métricas de recall/precision para las clases mas dificiles de clasificar. Todo esto debes de considerar.

Espero te sirva.